# What are @IBSegueAction valid method signatures?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am looking for a documentation for @IBSegueAction and valid method signatures? Variants are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic signature is:

1. First parameter is an NSCoder
2. Second parameter (the sender) is an `Any?` and may be omitted if the third parameter is omitted
3. Third parameter (the segue identifier) is a `String?` and may be omitted
4. Result is an Optional or non-Optional UIViewController or some subclass thereof. If it *is* Optional and you return `nil`, then the instantiation proceeds as if this call had never been made.

We may exemplify those rules by this declaration:

```
@IBSegueAction 
func f(coder:NSCoder, sender:Any?, ident:String?) -> UIViewController? {
```

with the understanding that all that matters is the signature: the function name and the parameter labels don't matter, the third or second-and-third parameters may be omitted, and the result type is rather broad in the way I've already outlined.

[Original documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11-release-notes), the rest determined by experimentation.]